# Zapier Code (JavaStep) Action: How to convert Server XML response body to JSON or JS Object?

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am trying to use Zapier Javascript code step to invoke a HTML query to a remote server. The server returns an XML response body that needs to be parsed further into a JSON object.

Firstly, I had some trouble finding a quick way to do this conversion. There are modules/packages that are available using JQuery and other frameworks, which are unsupported by Zapier (Zapier engine supports NodeJS 8.10.x without many additional modules/packages). The standard documentation seems to be created for a case returning JSON object already.

I have the following code, and I am experiencing error relative to that as well:

EDIT (06/05):
Based on the comment, I am posting the calling code to the method xml2JSON.

```js
let url = '<https://remote-sever-base-url?method, params etc.>'

let response = await fetch(url);

if (response.ok) { // if HTTP-status is 200-299
    // Response body is in XML format. No JSON available.

    var xmlDoc = await response.text();

    var jsondata = xmlToJson(xmlDoc); 

    console.log(jsonData);

} else {
    alert("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
}

// Changes XML to JSON
function xmlToJson(xml) {

    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
        obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }

    // do children
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

The error:
`The run javascript could not be sent to Code by Zapier.
TypeError: xml.hasChildNodes is not a function`

FYI - the incoming XML is pretty flat and predictable in its structure.

```
<result>
    <record>
          <field1>
          <field 2>
          ....fields continue
    </record>
    ...... list continues
</result>
```

Therefore the DOM does have child nodes, though not very deep tree.
Also, since these are records out of a relational DB, all record structures within a result set are similar, though between different POSTs they will differ. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: is there any other code in your code step? how do you call the `xmlToJson` function? Does the object you pass into the function have a `.hasChildNodes` property?

Comment: Calling code basically sends a HTTP request. Here's the code block appended with calling logic.

Answer (score 0):

When strung together, you're basically calling `(await response.text()).hasChildNodes()`, which is a function that doesn't exist (hence your error). `response.text()` resolves to a regular string, not any sort of XML object.

Instead of parsing it yourself, I'd recommend using the "Webhooks by Zapier" app to make your request - it'll do the XML parsing for you and return a json-like object you can use downstream.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. A dumb question: isn't webhooks only meant for connecting with those apps that publish changes/updates?  In my scenario the remote server does not publish change notifications, I need to poll it (and for that, I am using Scheduler followed by Code step). Secondly, is it possible to then just send raw response to this xml2js function for success?

Comment: Good question - the name is a bit of a misnomer. It's basically the "HTTP Request app" and has a lot of bells and whistles. For instance, it's got a "poll this endpoint" trigger that you can point at arbitrary endpoints.

Comment: For your second question, I don't think it's possible to parse xml with vanilla node.js, which is all that's in code steps. I'd try using the webhook poll trigger, but if that doesn't work you can make a simple CLI integration that'll handle it. Integrations can use `npm` packages, so you can use an XML parsing lib. There are docs [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/master/packages/cli/README.md#does-zapier-support-xml-soap-apis)

Comment: Thank you. Taking a look at webhooks. So, between a scheduler followed by code step and a webhook, which one will you recommend? :-)

Comment: Definitely the webhook! Scheduler should be saved for when you need something to happen at a specific time/frequency